# HURD: Why is remote process not killed?

Tags: shell, ssh, signals, hurd

On most UNIX systems this will not leave a process running:

```
ssh example.net sleep 1000
<<CTRL-C>>
```

I have tested this behaviour on

```
aix
centos
debian
dragonfly
freebsd
hpux
irix
mandriva
miros
netbsd
openbsd
openindiana
qnx
redhat
scosysv
solaris-x86
solaris
suse
tru64
ubuntu
unixware
```

They all clean up as expected. On HURD the login shell is killed as expected, but the sleep is left running as a child of init. Why? And can it be mitigated?

```
$ uname -a
GNU hurd 0.5 GNU-Mach 1.4-486/Hurd-0.5 i686-AT386 GNU

$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash

$ /bin/bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.24(1)-release (i486-pc-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: Which shell are you using?

Comment: A HURD mailing list might be a better place to ask this.

Comment: I get this same behavior in an LXC guest. And when ssh'ing into localhost... are you sure the behavior is how described in all those Unix's mentioned? I am on Debian here.

Comment: I just tested this on Ubuntu 14.04, and I get an orphaned sleep process unless I run ssh with "-t" to force a TTY for the session.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the Hurd FAQ you can find some information about this case:

> ??    What is the login shell?
>
> {MB} The Hurd has the concept of a not-logged in user.  This user has
>   neither user ids nor groups ids.  This stems from the fact that the
>   Hurd supports uid and gid sets and one possibility is, of course, the
>   empty set.  Rather than deny access in this case, filesystems in the
>   Hurd offer a fourth permission triplet (i.e. rwx) which is used to
>   determine the privileges for users with no credentials.  This,
>   however, needs to be enabled on a file by file basis.  By default, the
>   `other' permission triplet is used.
>
> The Hurd login shell is a shell running with neither uids nor gids. 
>   To restrict access to your files, either enable and change the fourth
>   permission triplet or change the login shell of the 'login' user in
>   the password file to '/bin/loginpr' which implements the standard
>   login prompt.

And remember, Hurd is not UNIX. Its a replacement for the UNIX kernel, using the Match Microkernel, so, many of the concepts from UNIX are not applicable to Hurd.

> Mach is a micro-kernel, written at Carnegie Mellon University.  A more
>   descriptive term might be a greatest-common-factor kernel, since it
>   provides facilities common to all ``real'' operating systems, such as
>   memory management, inter-process communication, processes, and a bunch
>   of other stuff.  Unfortunately, the system calls used to access these
>   facilities are only vaguely related to the familiar and cherished Unix
>   system calls.  There are no "fork", "wait", or "sleep" system-calls,
>   no SIGHUPs, nothing like that.  All this makes it rather difficult to,
>   say, port GNU Emacs to a Mach box.

References:

- [GNU Hurd FAQ inlined](http://www.gnu.org/software/hurd/faq_inlined.html)
- [GNU Hurd Documentation - Authentication](http://www.gnu.org/software/hurd/hurd-talk.html#aut)